# Can we remove the ( ) bracket from Theorem 1.2.1 ( [7])

Tags: citing, theorems

Can we remove the ( ) bracket from the environment like Theorem 1.2.1 ( [7]).

Comment: Why didn't you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) in your previous post (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146714/27635) instead of posting a new question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove brackets from the optional title in amsthm?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52621/how-to-remove-brackets-from-the-optional-title-in-amsthm)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino -- that question is similar, but the used of `\swappedhead` makes the situation not equivalent.  the answer i've just posted is a more general one.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: good point: I'll retract the close vote!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9):

this can be accomplished by defining a `\newtheoremstyle` when using `amsthm`.

here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%% goal is to omit parens from note, place cite as part of theorem number
\newtheoremstyle{cited}%
  {3pt}% (space above)
  {3pt}% (space below)
  {\itshape}% (body font)
  {}% (indent amount)
  {\bfseries}% {theorem head font}
  {.}% {punctuation after theorem head}
  {.5em}% {space after theorem head}
  {\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2} \thmnote{\normalfont#3}}% {theorem head spec}

\theoremstyle{cited}
\newtheorem{citedthm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{citedthm}[\cite{xxx}]
this theorem is borrowed from somewhere else.
\end{citedthm}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{xxx}
this is a bibitem.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(i'm sure a very similar question was asked within the past few days,
because i had already experimented with this problem, but i can't find it.
i would also like to thank @mafp, who provided a similar answer in the
question [How to remove parentheses when I refer to some lemma or proposition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101378/579).)

**edit:** in a comment, it has been requested that there be no space between the theorem
number and the cited reference.  to accomplish that, omit the space from the
"theorem spec" line (the last line of the `\newtheoremstyle` definition):

```
  {\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}\thmnote{\normalfont#3}}% {theorem head spec}
```

in this situation, when sometimes there is a "cited" theorem and sometimes a "non-cited"
theorem, the same numbering system can be used like this:

```
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{cited}
\newtheorem{citedthm}[thm]{Theorem}
```

specifying the optional argument `[thm]` between the name of the new theorem environment
and its heading text will cause the same counter to be used as already defined when
the `{thm}` environment is set up.

Comment: But in this case I also got Theorem 1 .     where [1] is not used then how we remove the space between Theorem 1 and .

Comment: @DeepeshPatel -- that's a different (standard) presentation of a theorem:  `\theoremstyel{plain} \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}` in the preamble, and use it as `\begin{thm} ... \end{thm}` in the body.  if you do use `amsthm`, it's a good idea to read the documentation: `texdoc amsthm`.  (it's not very long, only five pages.)

Comment: When I use the \theoremstyle{plain} then again I got like Theorem 1.2 ([7]).   Actualy I want Theorem 1.2[7]. and in case there is no like [7] then Theorem 1.2.

Comment: @DeepeshPatel -- distinguishing between these two situations isn't easy to do automatically.  it shouldn't be that difficult to make that decision on input.  see my edits.

Comment: Yes, it is working like that I want. Thank you very much for your kind support.

Comment: @DeepeshPatel -- if this answer provides the result you want, you can accept it by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer.