# Citing a theorem with a superscripted number in square brackets

Tags: citing

I have a problem regarding citing a theorem. 
This is a current code that I am using.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage[numbers, square, super]{natbib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\NAT@citesuper[3]{\ifNAT@swa
\if*#2*\else#2\NAT@spacechar\fi
\unskip\kern\p@\textsuperscript{\NAT@@open#1#3\NAT@@close}%
\else #1\fi\endgroup}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{dfn}{Definice}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{dfn} [{\cite{1}}]
A definition.
\end{dfn}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{1} A bibitem.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

I would like my theorem to look like this, except for the large curly brackets.

[image: I would like my theorem to look like this, except for the large curly brackets.]

Comment: It shows up exactly like in the picture, no curly brackets. What do you not want?

Comment: Hi, I am sorry, I am new to this website. Could you please tell me how you put that code in that box as you have suggested?(I will then upload a new question ) And unfortunately, it does not appear to me withouth brackets like you say..

Comment: Click the "edit" button below the question, then highlight the code in your question and click the button with the two curly braces.

Comment: Do not ask a new question, by the way, just edit this one using the edit button, right below where the {citing} tag is.

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't just write `[{\cite{1}}]`. Instead, write a mini-sentence, say, `[see {\cite{1}}]`.

Comment: Yes, that would be possible, but I would like the one above without the brackets..Is there a salution to this? Thank you in advance

Comment: Refer this link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146859/75818

Comment: You can use `\thcite{1}` instead of `[{\cite{1}}]`, after defining `\thcite` in the preamble as follows: `\newcommand\thcite[1]{\hspace*{-\labelsep}{\bfseries\upshape\cite{#1}}}`

Comment: @gernot Thank you very much!! It works perfectly :))